# Loop skipping first line of text file being read, working for second line, but also not reading third line

Tags: bash

I have a text file with different usernames being read into a loop in Bash. Each one of these is on its own line. I want to perform the actions within this loop for each username in the text file. I think the issue may have to do with the fact I'm calling another script but I'm not sure. Here's an example of the text file

```
bobsmith123
jimjenkins456
susanjones789
```

I'm then grabbing some information from AD by using an LDAP search and then passing this information to another script by use of env variables. However, the first line of the file is skipped entirely, the second line works correctly, and the third line seems to not read the username from the text file but performs all of the actions, resulting in an error in the script being called as `$CENTRIFY_USER` is empty. Any help is appreciated. Here is my script.

```
echo "Enter username for LDAP Search"

read USERNAME
export USERNAME

echo "Enter password"

read -s PASSWORD
export PASSWORD

echo "What user do you want to add to Centrify?"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
read CENTRIFY_USER
export CENTRIFY_USER


OBJECTSID=`ldapsearch -H ldap://my.domain.com:389 -D "$USERNAME@MY.DOMAIN.COM" -w $PASSWORD -x -b "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com" "(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=$CENTRIFY_USER))" | grep objectSid | cut -d " " -f2`
SID=`/home/myhome/convert_objectSid_to_sid.sh $OBJECTSID`

export SID

echo "Adding user to Centrify..."
/home/myhome/add_users_to_centrify.sh
done < centrify_users_to_add.txt
```

Comment: Your loop starts with reading the first line into `line` (on the `while` line). Then, you do `read CENTRIFY_USER`, which reads the *next* line; you never do anything with `line`. Each loop processes two lines, throwing away the odd one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop, you do *two* reads.  The first is `read -r line` reads the first line then `read CENTRIFY_USER` which is the second line.  You do not appear to be using `$line` in you script.

You appear to need:

```
while IFS='' read -r CENTRIFY_USER; do

    export CENTRIFY_USER

    .... 

    done < centrify_users_to_add.txt
```

Comment: Of course, I was converting this from a script that originally prompted the user each time. Thanks, somehow didn't see this.